# Python comprehension consolidation

Tags: python, parsing, list-comprehension

I feel there must be an easier (cleaner) way to use comprehensions to parse the meminfo file on linux.  The format of the file is:

```
MemTotal:        3045588 kB
MemFree:         1167060 kB
Buffers:          336752 kB
Cached:           721980 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           843592 kB
Inactive:         752920 kB
Active(anon):     539968 kB
Inactive(anon):   134472 kB
```

I tried to rewrite the `for` loop id been using to use a comprehension and found I needed 3 of them...

```
def parse_mem_file(memfile = '/proc/meminfo'):
    lines = open(memfile, 'r').readlines()
    lines = [line.strip('kB\n') for line in lines if line[-3:] == 'kB\n']
    lines = [line.split(':') for line in lines]
    return dict((key, int(value)) for (key, value) in lines)

print parse_mem_file()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a reasonable way to simplify this?

Comment: Short answer: regex.  But then you have two problems.

Comment: @Ignacio - there is no dict-comprehension tag

Comment: The third is a generator expression.

Comment: Oh, right. thanks. I started with the py3 docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open(f) as fin:
    for l in fin:
        x = l.split()
        d[x[0][:-1]] = int(x[1])
return d
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this version much more readable:

```
def parse_mem_file(memfile='/proc/meminfo'):
    data = {}
    with open(memfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            key, value, size = line.split()
            if size == 'kB':
                data[key[:-1]] = int(value)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution(note that i have used string data - so in your case you need to modify code to read data from a file):

```
data = """
MemTotal:        3045588 kB
MemFree:         1167060 kB
Buffers:          336752 kB
Cached:           721980 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           843592 kB
Inactive:         752920 kB
Active(anon):     539968 kB
Inactive(anon):   134472 kB
"""

res = {}

for line in [x for x in d.split('\n') if x.strip() and ':' in x and 'kB' in x]:
    details = line.split()
    res[details[0][:-1]] = details[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex and a list comprehension:

```
def parse_mem_file(memfile = '/proc/meminfo'):
    with open(memfile, 'r') as meminfo:
        return dict(
            (m.group(1), int(m.group(2)))
            for m in [re.match('(.+):\\s*(\\d+)', line) for line in meminfo]
            if m is not None)
```